# Recyclerview findViewHolderForAdapterPosition returns null after scroll to new position

Tags: android-recyclerview

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
MyAdapter mAdapter;
List<ItemData> itemsData;
Global glb;
LinearLayoutManager llm;

private int valData() {
    String tmpStr;
    Cursor c;
    int position=0;
enter code here
    AutoCompleteTextView tTbl = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.tblNam);
    tmpStr = tTbl.getText().toString();
    c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tblDts WHERE tblNam = '" + tmpStr + "'", null);
    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
        showMessage("Error", "Table Name Not Found");
        c.close();
        tTbl.requestFocus();
        return 1;
    }
    c.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemsData.size(); i++) {
        tmpStr = itemsData.get(i).getTitle().toString();
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM itmDts WHERE itmNam = '" + tmpStr + "';", null);
        if (c.getCount() == 0) {

            c.close();

            //llm.scrollToPositionWithOffset(i,0);
            //recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(i);
            //recyclerView.scrollToPosition(i);
```

i tried all the above scroll procedure, when i using getChildAt its return only view of the before scroll and not the new one

```
            //View vw = llm.getChildAt(0);
            tmpStr="";
```

when rise the findviewholderforadapterpostion in between current display views there has been it shows correctly but if i rise non display position it returns null
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
                View vw = vh.itemView;

```
            AutoCompleteTextView tTa=(AutoCompleteTextView)vw.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            tmpStr =tTa.getText().toString();


            showMessage(llm.getChildCount()+"Error" + position, "Item Name Not Found" + tmpStr);

            //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);


            return 1;
        }
        c.close();

    }
    return 0;
}


   }
}
```

Comment: did you resolve this problem?

Comment: recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(0)
refer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885863/onbindviewholder-is-never-called-on-view-at-position-even-though-recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885863/onbindviewholder-is-never-called-on-view-at-position-even-though-recyclerview)

Comment: recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(0) [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885863/onbindviewholder-is-never-called-on-view-at-position-even-though-recyclerview)

Answer (score 0):

I am always facing with these kind of problems on Android platform. And most of my problems fixed with thread sleep :) This is not a proper way but could not found any other way. Just you need to add 100 ms sleep after scrolled the next item.

Following code is for Xamarin.Android.

```
public async static void FocusNextItem(Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView recyclerView, int nextPosition)
    {
        recyclerView.ScrollToPosition(nextPosition);

        var viewHolder = recyclerView.FindViewHolderForAdapterPosition(nextPosition);
        if (viewHolder == null)
        {
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100);

            viewHolder = recyclerView.FindViewHolderForAdapterPosition(nextPosition);
        }
        viewHolder?.ItemView?.RequestFocus();
    }
```

Comment: Yes Saret, you are right but I could not find correct way to handle this kind of problems.

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem and I have also resolved to using Thread sleep. I also know that it doesn't look like a good solution but there doesn't seem to be any callback that we could use for this purpose. Have you managed to think of some other solution?