# Change offscreen limit for recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

On my android application, I'm opening recycler view cell (increasing its height with animation).

If I'm opening it just on the top of recycler view - it scrolls top a little and top (offscreen) item is going to recycle and at the bottom of the recycler, the view appears another cell with opened content.

Tested with little smaller height to open - everything works fine.

So the question is, how to say to recycler view to give me a little bit more height on top offscreen before starting the recycling element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Use a LayoutManager that supports "extra" space. Consult the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#getExtraLayoutSpace(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State))

The answer was originally posted [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2npsmb/any_way_to_precache_views_in_a_recyclerview/)

The following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460762/whats-the-difference-between-recyclerview-setitemviewcachesize-and-recycledview/49460900) may also be useful.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!

Comment: Already solved other problem that makes that problem go away. But for future, that answer can help, thanks